# Sip authentication --response value

Tags: sip, asterisk, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate myself with my asterisk server but I don't think that I am formatting the authentication header correctly, specifically the response value.  I'm using the following formula to create the MD5 hash for the value:

```
            String a = sipLayer.MD5Encoder("username:realm:password");
        String b = sipLayer.MD5Encoder("REGISTER:sip:username@10.2.0.53:61469");

        String c = sipLayer.MD5Encoder(String.format("%s:%s", a,b));
```

There doesn't seem to be a very active sip community, hence it is very difficult to find anything on google. 
Here are my sip packets from the server.  Can anybody see anything that is wrong?  Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.  I can't even begin to explain it in a forum post.  If somebody has a similar problem, feel free to message or email me and I will be glad to explain it.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, there is a *very* active SIP implementer community.  Check out the sip-implementors mailing list - https://lists.cs.columbia.edu/mailman/listinfo/sip-implementors